# stringByReplacingMatchesInString: returns (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ios4, nsregularexpression

Here is my code:

```
NSRegularExpression * regex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<*>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
}

- (IBAction)findWord {  
    NSString * fileContents=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/report1_index1_page1.html", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",fileContents);

    NSString * modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:fileContents
                                                                options:0
                                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [fileContents length])
                                                           withTemplate:@"$1"];

    NSLog(@"%@",modifiedString);
}
```

My 'modifiedString' is returning (null).Why?I want to replace any characters between '<' and '>' including '<' and '>' simply by a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing this has a lot to do with the fact that you are assigning an autoreleased object to `regex` in `viewDidLoad`. Try adding a `retain` or move the line to the `findWord` method.

#### Regex

The regular expression for matching everything between `<` and `>` is incorrect. The correct way would be,

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=<).*(?=>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if ( error ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

#### Replace by space

If you want to replace the matched string with `" "` then you shouldn't pass `$1` as the template. Rather, use `" "` as the template.

```
NSString * modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:fileContents
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [fileContents length])
                                                       withTemplate:@" "];
```

Comment: Is there any mistake in my regular expression or the method to declare it?I am not sure.

Comment: Are you still gett `null` or not getting the desired result? If so, can you do `NSLog(@"%@", regex);` and let me know what it prints?

Comment: @Deepak:NSLog(@"%@", regex); also prints (null)

Comment: Does it do the same in `viewDidLoad`? You might want to check if `error` is not `nil` and then log it as well. If `regex` is not `nil` in `viewDidLoad` then what happens when you add that code in `findWord`?

Comment: @Deepak:Its really confusing.In viewDidLoad also regex is coming (null), error is also coming (null).What is done wrong here?

Comment: Strange as your code didn't give me `nil` objects. I can't tell for sure why it is the case but try replacing your code with the code I added to my answer. It seems to be working as per your requirement.

Comment: @Deepak:Yes.I had tried with " " but it gave nil so tried $ but it didn't work either.

Comment: So What happens when you put the entire code in a single method i.e. `findWord` and run?

Comment: @Deepak:Not sure what is the problem but this code is also returning (null).I have added all the code to     findWord.I am sure this is going to be a silly mistake but not able to find it.

Comment: Here's a [`sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/RegEx.zip). Check the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. It has the code that matches what I posted in the answer and if you run it, you will see that it works. Not sure why it isn't working on your side though.

Comment: @Deepak:Yes,At least got something.I am getting log as follows:        Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
ache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
ction getName, file /SourceCache

Comment: Yes your sample is working but if I paste the same code in my function then it gives (null).

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running this on?

Comment: Are you facing this problem in the simulator or device? Have you check with the other? Some source mention the error you posted as problem with the simulator and some say you need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @Deepak:Oh!Is it like that?I haven't checked it with device really.But the sample which you gave is working perfectly in simulator also.I think some project settings has to be done.

Comment: Ok.Have you checked with same code in an IBAction as my code is in a method.I have pasted the same code,even website name is also same.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. It takes time but does the job.

Comment: Here also it does take the time but returns null

Comment: @Deepak:Hay,that was just because I had made Deployment SDK Target as 3.1.3.It should be at least 4.0 to be able to use NSRegularExpression.Thanks for the help.It made me able to understand and solve the problem.My guess is I should use any readymade framework if the application should be able to run on iOS 3.2 :)